# Exclude Liferay's OSGI bundle on Startup

Tags: liferay

I have installed Liferay 7 to develop application. When Liferay 7 started, I found that it started more then 400+ OSGI bundles/services. So is there any way that we configure Liferay to only load specific bundles only? Or we can provide list of OSGI bundles/services to be excluded on start up of Liferay?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the ones that you don't need. This way they won't be started. Note that there might be dependent bundles that also won't start when their dependencies are not met, but you probably expected that. So if you're missing functionality after removing some bundles, you probably have deleted too many of them (or the wrong ones).

Comment: So from which folder do I have to delete the bundle? I can see "OSGI" folder and "work" folder inside portal server at parallel to tomcat directory. So for example i wanted to delete Liferay Marketplace related OSGI bundle then which JAR file do i need to remove from which directory?

Comment: I don't have an installation at hand to try it, so I can't say for sure. You can also start with just stopping bundles from liferay's gogo shell. `lb | grep market`  and `stop 4711` where 4711 is the bundle id that you've identified. You can then identify which other bundles have been stopped as well.

Comment: Just stopping the bundle will not help, because it will be restarted again when server is restarted. So, can you please provide exact way how to remove a particular bundle when liferay started?

Comment: with manual stops you'll figure out the dependent bundles (try `lb | grep installed` and `lb | grep resolved` afterwards). The stopped bundle's name should give you a hint for the filenames to look for. Try it a bit - I know that it is working, but haven't been through extensive exercise and specifically not fully memorized all the steps. The dirty details are for you to try out - I'm answering on my phone which doesn't have any Liferay installation that I could play with.

Comment: I have tried, it gives details of file in "State" folder bundle. For e.g. if bundle ID is 501 then it will create "501" folder inside "state" folder. This folder is created automatically when OSGI bundle is loaded runtime, so deleting that bundle will not work. I need to delete bundle from actual directory/place where it loads from.